# discord.js message.startThread() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I found this example for creating threads in the official discord.js guide, but it doesn't work...

```js
const thread = await message.startThread({
    name: 'food-talk',
    autoArchiveDuration: 60,
    reason: 'Needed a separate thread for food',
});
```

It returns `message.startThread is not a function`
What is the correct function to do this?

Full Error:

```
(node:1727) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.startThread is not a function
(node:1727) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1727) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Which version of Discord.js are you using? Are you sure that the message is not a partial message?

Comment: discord.js is version 12.5.3, the message is not partial

Comment: `startThread` is only available since v13

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros thanks, i didnt know that - i'll go update the package and it should work after that ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is already solved but here is all you need to do for people who just found this post on google.

```
npm i discord.js@latest
```